# svnadmin: Expected FS format '2'; found format '4

Tags: svn

I am doing migration of SVN from an old Linux server to a new Linux server which is on different network.

I tried to take the backup of the svn by using the svnadmin dump command but it failed with the below error. svnadmin: Expected FS format '2'; found format '4'

I thought of using the svn sync option but we don't have the network connectivity between old and new server.

Please could some one help me in this.

Regards,
Madhu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository is a BDB format repository with format number 4.  You're using a Subversion 1.4.x `svnadmin` command against it which doesn't know that format (it only knows up to format 2).  You need to use at least Subversion 1.6.x of `svnadmin`.  I'd guess you have an OS packaged version of Subversion which happens to be 1.4.x and have also installed 1.6.x (or newer) which is what the server is using.  I'd look for where the `svnadmin` command that goes with the server software is.